# Django object retrieval not working

Tags: python, json, django, blockchain

For some reason UserProfile.objects.all() isn't retrieving the models I have to serialize them as json. Any ideas?

views.py

```
def get_modelAPI(request):
    UserProfile_json = serializers.serialize("json", UserProfile.objects.all())
    data = {"UserProfile_json": UserProfile_json}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^details/json/$', views.get_modelAPI, name='json'),
```

models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    fullName = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    address = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    dob = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    homePhone = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    personalPhone = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    emergencyContact = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    ppsn = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    maritalStatus = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    employment = models.CharField(max_length = 250)
    personalPic = models.CharField(max_length = 1000)
```

I am simply attempting to view this model in json format for now later to be parsed.

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZTGr.png)

Extra information:
By changing my get_modelAPI to:

```
def get_modelAPI(request):
    UserProfile_json = serializers.serialize("json", 
    UserProfile.objects.all())
    data = {"UserProfile_json": [UserProfile]}
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

I get:
[New data returned to webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Ylh.png)

What I want to do is get the model e.g fullName: 'John Smith' which I have in my database along with the rest of the models, parse this to json.

[Shell screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeXFt.png)

Comment: If you try to do this in shell, or take a peak at your database, are you certain that there are actual entries in your db? The issue could range from the user profile not actually being created, to possibly overwriting the objects manager in your user, to a range of other things so I would need a bit more info to help.

Comment: Are you sure that `UserProfile` has at least one object in DB?

Comment: Extra information added. Yes the database has 2 users that are connected to 2 individual UserProfiles. Currently I am not trying to get the information but just retrieve that models.

Comment: How do you know there are 2 UserProfiles in the db? did you run UserProfile.objects.all() in the shell? Sorry to keep harping on this point, Just want to make sure the data is there for sure.

Comment: Added screenshot of shell. I believe this shows that I do have UserProfile objects and also when I go into admin I can see there that they also exist

Comment: Where are you importing serializers from?

Comment: from django.core import serializers